# Open SAML xml-apis Maven Dependency Issue

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, grails, xerces

I'm trying to add the Open SAML libraries to my Grails project through Maven. So to the `pom.xml` I added the open SAML dependencies:

```
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId> 
        <artifactId>opensaml</artifactId> 
        <version>2.5.1-1</version> 
    </dependency> 

    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId> 
        <artifactId>openws</artifactId> 
        <version>1.4.2-1</version> 
    </dependency> 

    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId> 
        <artifactId>xmltooling</artifactId> 
        <version>1.3.2-1</version>
    </dependency>
```

`grails run-app` and `mvn install` had worked fine, but when I place the built war file into tomcat 8 I get the following errors on startup:

```
2015-07-22 11:17:53,091 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.ContextLoader  -       Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.ElementTraversal
    ... 7 more
```

From a little research I found out that xml-apis:xml-apis:1.4.01 should be added to my pom file so that it appears in the WEB-INF/lib folder of the unpackaged war. Thus I added the following dependency to my pom file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.01</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Also I inspected the dependency tree generated by `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` and found:

```
+- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
+- org.opensaml:opensaml:jar:2.5.1-1:compile
|  +- (org.opensaml:openws:jar:1.4.2-1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.1:compile
|  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.1:compile
|  +- velocity:velocity:jar:1.5:compile
|  |  +- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  |  \- (commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- org.owasp.esapi:esapi:jar:2.0GA:compile
|  +- (xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.10.0:runtime
|  |  \- (xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:runtime
|  \- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1:runtime
|     \- xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1:runtime
|        \- (xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.04:runtime - omitted for conflict with 1.4.01)
+- org.opensaml:openws:jar:1.4.2-1:compile
|  +- (org.opensaml:xmltooling:jar:1.3.2-1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.3:compile
|  +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
|  |  \- (commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.3)
|  +- (xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- (xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.10.0:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- (xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
|  \- (xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
+- org.opensaml:xmltooling:jar:1.3.2-1:compile
|  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile
|  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
|  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
|  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
|  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.8.1:compile
|  +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15:jar:1.45:compile
|  +- org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:jar:1.4.4:compile
|  +- ca.juliusdavies:not-yet-commons-ssl:jar:0.3.9:compile
|  |  \- (commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.1)
|  +- net.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0:compile
|  +- (xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- (xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.10.0:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
|  +- (xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
|  \- (xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
```

It seems the desired xml-apis jar would then be packaged int the war file so to be in WEB-INF/lib, but after building the war with `mvn install` with this in the pom file I still get the above No Class Found Errors and the xml-apis jar doesn't appear in the WEB-INF/lib folder still. I think I followed the usual prescription for this issue, but I'm still unable to resolve this issue. Does anyone know why the xml-apis dependency is not being packaged into the war file, or why this error appears during Tomcat startup? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by excluding the xerces:xercesImpl jar from all the Open SAML dependencies in the POM.

The Open SAML dependencies in the POM look like:

```
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId> 
        <artifactId>opensaml</artifactId> 
        <version>2.5.1-1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xerces</groupId> 
                <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId> 
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId> 
        <artifactId>openws</artifactId> 
        <version>1.4.2-1</version> 
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xerces</groupId> 
                <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId> 
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId> 
        <artifactId>xmltooling</artifactId> 
        <version>1.3.2-1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xerces</groupId> 
                <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId> 
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```